# How to store separate versions of document for a blog using mongodb with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, versioning

I am creating a blog site but i would like to add the feature to have history for a blog what changes are been done in previous version and latest version. Creating a separate history collection will be one approach but what about the document do i need to just copy the document of old revision in history collection or the just the json diff . If we just store the  diff of field what will be the base object to construct the upto date document till that revision if we wish to query document with specific revision suppose (__version: 15) and current version will be somewhere 25.

Comment: There's no way to answer this objectively. You'll only get opinions and discussion.

Comment: @DavidMakogon looking for opinions only

Comment: Right - but... that's not what StackOverflow is for. And you accepted someone's answer which is merely an opinion, and in no way a definitive answer. And I can *easily* argue the assertion that it's better to have a separate collection for history.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd go with your first option, using a history collection, since it would be easier to fetch an entire document than keeping lot of diffs and then having to sync them all together. Also, having a different collectiont would be a faster solution, since you wouldn't need to fetch for different versions, assemble them and display it.

But on the other side, if you just want to show minor changes, like on facebook when you edit a comment, I think the diff approach would be the best option, altough you'd have to keep references on where and what has changed

Comment: Why is a different collection for history a faster solution? I don't see why that would be. And why are minor changes better as diffs? In any case - this is just one opinion of one (actually two) approaches.

Comment: Because you can quickly fetch the documents by the "original" id (indexed) for instance. What is the point of saving the entire document, having to go through both versions to see what has changed if you can save only what actually changed ?

Comment: @Leonardo totally agree with this technique to save only diffs but my doubt is how easy it would be construct a object if we want to see the object at specific version suppose ( __v: 15 )

Comment: Ok, so for each version you'd create a new object with the version number + 1, right ? So, you'd simply query for the original_id + the version you'd like !